# Filtering listbox using textbox using Linq but listbox stays full

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am unable to filter listbox data using linq and textbox.Listbox values don 't change when I enter text to be filtered inside the textbox. This function is important so that I can send the data to another form which contains the listbox.

```
        public void GetList(List<SemesterDetails> modules)
    {
        
        string filter = txtFilter.Text;
        foreach (var item in modules.Where(m => m.ModuleName.Contains(filter)))
        {
           
            LstModules.Items.Add(item);
        }
  
    }
```

I tried to call the function to the textbox event function:

```
    private void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    List<SemesterDetails> semesters = new List<SemesterDetails>();

        GetList(semesters);
        
    }
```

The result is:
Items remain unfiltered in the listbox.

Comment: Set a breakpoint before `GetList(semesters);` and examine `semesters`.

Comment: `semesters` is an empty list, so there isn't anything to filter.

Comment: You should consider clearing your ListBox before adding items to it in the filter.

Comment: When I add clear Listbox prior, I get no items

Comment: According to your post, that's what you want.  We don't know where you are getting your `semesters` list, because you are just creating an empty list and passing it to `GetList`.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<SemesterDetails> semesters = new List<SemesterDetails>();
GetList(semesters);
```

This is an empty list.

```
public void GetList(List<SemesterDetails> modules)
{
    string filter = txtFilter.Text;
    foreach (var item in modules.Where(m => m.ModuleName.Contains(filter)))
    {
        LstModules.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Since you're passing in an empty list, the `foreach` will be executed 0 times, and therefore nothing can ever be added.

The filtering is irrelevant in this scenario.

> Items remain unfiltered in the listbox

Nowhere in your code do you ever remove the items that are already in the listbox. Therefore, it's not possible for the listbox' contents to reduce.

> When I add clear Listbox prior, I get no items

If you clear a list and then not add items to it (as discussed above), an empty list is indeed the logical outcome.

Comment: How can I get the listbox to remove the values?

Comment: @Jacob: That question is immediately answered when pasted verbatim into your search engine of choice. Secondly, you commented _"When I add clear Listbox prior, I get no items"_ two minutes before posting your above comment, so it seems you already knew the answer.